# rest namespace not recoginzed in custom REST API class

Tags: 8

I'm working on creating my first custom REST resource in D8, and following [this blog post](http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/12/16/how-to-create-a-rest-resource-in-drupal-8/), I have the following class in the /modules/custom/video_export/src/Plugin/rest/resource directory:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Custom Rest resource for video nodes.
 */

namespace Drupal\video_export\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a resource for database watchdog log entries.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "video_export_source",
 *   label = @Translation("Video Export Source"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/videos/feed/{site}"
 *   }
 * )
 */

class VideoExportResource extends ResourceBase {
  /**
   *  A curent user instance.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
    * @param array $configuration
    *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
    * @param string $plugin_id
    *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
    * @param mixed $plugin_definition
    *   The plugin implementation definition.
    * @param array $serializer_formats
    *   The available serialization formats.
    * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    *   A logger instance.
    * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $current_user
    *   A current user instance.
  */
  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    array $serializer_formats,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    AccountProxyInterface $current_user) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $serializer_formats, $logger);

    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('rest'),
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
    * Responds to GET requests.
    *
    * Returns a list of video nodes to be imported into the target site.
    *
    * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
    *   The response containing a list of bundle names.
    *
    * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
 */
  public function get($site = NULL) {
    $response = ['message' => 'Hello, this is a rest service'];
    return new ResourceResponse($response);
  }
}
```

However, I'm having multiple problems trying to use this code:

First, my IDE (PHPStorm) is not recognizing the `namespace` keyword. In addition, in my the `rest` dir in that path is highlighted in red, and it shows an error message on the `resource` keyword that says

> Undefined constant resource: declaration of referenced constant is not
>   found in built-in library and project files.

I've verified that I have the RESTful Web Services module enabled.

Also, I have the REST UI module enabled, and it lists my resource, but when I try to enable it, it tells me `undefined namespace Drupal\video_export\Plugin\rest\resource'`, which I'm sure is because of the other errors.

I've looked this over and over and can't see what's wrong

Comment: Sometimes for me in PHPStorm doesn't recognize namespace for the first type either. Copy it, delete the line, and paste it.

Comment: @Jdrupal We don't need the _rest_ tag. If it has been removed, there is a reason.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by the comment by @ssibal, I just had to remove the line and then manually add it back in. The second time it took fine, and my resource works now.